# How to implement a remote scheduler server using python

Tags: python, serialization, scheduler

I wanna use python to implement a remote scheduler server which provide API for others to call. For example, user can make a POST request to url http://myurl.com/Jobs with data

`{'job_name': 'Test1', 'job_func': function111, 'job_func_args': '111, 222', 'from_time': '11:25:00', 'to_time': 18:50:00', 'interval': 5, 'unit': 'second', 'isEveryDay': 0}`

then the specific function `function111` will run at the specific interval at specific duration. I use `APScheduler` for my scheduler, use `web.py` as web server.

Now my biggest question is **How to transmit customized function from client to scheduler server**! For simple function, I can use `marshal.dumps(function111.func_code)` to transmit, howerver, it dose not work for complex function which contains customized class instance as its arguments. Am I clear?

Dose RPC can satisfy my requirement? Or are there any other solutions to do with my problem?

Comment: In general it's an extremely bad idea to allow other users or processes to run arbitrary code on your server.

Comment: @Blubber, I know there is big security issue, any other solutions?

Comment: If security is not part of your system, then you can simply just transmit the python source in the file then dynamically load it, but as stated this is not a good design at all. I would rethink your problem if you're thinking this is the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: How about http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/

Comment: @AndreyKaygorodov, I am on this library, but I can't find a suitable example like my problem

Comment: @sean, I have thought your solution, first find the dependent module, compile it to .pyc, transmit the pyc over network, reload the pyc. That's really rough!